# Trying to get dynamic file location path

Tags: php, wordpress

Im integrating wordpress into my website and want to use my existing 'header' inside and outside of wordpress. The header contains an image. 
The Image SRC is currently "img/logo.png" but when header is required in wordpress that path isnt relative so no image is shown.

How can I get a path that works for the image both inside and outside word press.

I've tried

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mywebsite/img/logo.png'; ?>
```

which looks to output the correct uri in chrome inspector, but when hovering over the path its prefixed with the website root before  like such:

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/D:/program files/wamp/www/mywebsite
```

Comment: Another solution I've just discovered  is to use the "base" tag to set my wordpress base url as my website folder instead of the /blog folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
echo "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/mywebsite/img/logo.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

show you a local path to site root in OS

If you know that the current script from where you try to get a path relative to web root, then you can use a code below.

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); // site root of web server
$currentDir = realpath(__DIR__); // OS path to current directory where php file
$pathFromRoot = substr($currentDir, strlen($root)); // path related to web root
if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR != '/') // replace directory separator if windows
    $pathFromRoot = str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', $pathFromRoot);
echo $pathFromRoot;
```

But please keep in mind, if you are using rewrite rules for web server this path can be another than used in url.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using "wordpress", put the file into the "theme" and use this:

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/img/logo.png';?>
```

If your "img/logo.png" is in the root of your wordpress, use this:

```
<?php bloginfo('url').'/img/logo.png'; ?>
```